# Elastic NEST Client: updating data

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to update existing data.
Is there a better way than
Retrieve old data -> modify old data -> delete old index -> create new index -> bulk insert new data
This seems kind of stupid. Moreover I end up having approx. 2 times higher `store.size` per `index`.
I cannot figure out why this could be.

Directly bulkinserting modified data does not work: `docs.count` doubles.

Any ideas?

**Update**

This is my bulk insert:

```
 var dataPointsBulkIndexOperationsPerBatchId = data.Select(
                item => new BulkIndexOperation<T>(item)
                            {
                                Index = indexName
                            });

            var allBulksRequest = new BulkRequest
                                      {
                                          Operations = new BulkOperationsCollection<IBulkOperation>(dataPointsBulkIndexOperationsPerBatchId),
                                          Refresh = Refresh.True
                                      };

            if (allBulksRequest.Operations.Any())
            {
                var bulkResponse = elasticClient.Bulk(allBulksRequest);
                bulkResponse.AssertResponseIsValidAndSuccessful();
            }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: I am sorry I don't really get the point. This is more of a conceptual question. Or are my observations somewhat "suspicious" ?

Comment: You can directly bulk update the index. Behind the scene it will delete document and insert new as any change causes re indexing.

Comment: yes but how? I am using bulk insert as in updated topic

Comment: Check this link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/please-explain-how-to-perform-a-bulk-update-with-partials-using-updatemany/183873/4

Comment: okay thanks but I think don't see how I could get a reference to the existing doument which I need to perform the actual update because it depends on the model's state.

Answer (score 1):

For updating many documents in one request, you basically have two options:

#### 1. Bulk API with update operations

Using the [bulk API and sending a batch of update operations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update). Each update operation exposes the same options as you have with the update API, so can perform partial updates, scripted updates, etc.

An example of a scripted update

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var updates = new[] {
    new { Id = 1, Counter = 3 },
    new { Id = 2, Counter = 6 },
    new { Id = 3, Counter = 5 },
    new { Id = 4, Counter = 4 },
};

var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
    .Index("my_index")
    .UpdateMany(updates, (descriptor, update) => descriptor
        .Id(update.Id)
        .Script(s => s
            .Source("ctx._source.counter += params.counter")
            .Params(p => p
                .Add("counter", update.Counter)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which sends the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/my_index/_bulk
{"update":{"_id":1}}
{"script":{"source":"ctx._source.counter += params.counter","params":{"counter":3}}}
{"update":{"_id":2}}
{"script":{"source":"ctx._source.counter += params.counter","params":{"counter":6}}}
{"update":{"_id":3}}
{"script":{"source":"ctx._source.counter += params.counter","params":{"counter":5}}}
{"update":{"_id":4}}
{"script":{"source":"ctx._source.counter += params.counter","params":{"counter":4}}}
```

With scripted updates, you have access to the `_source` document within the script through `ctx._source`, so this example increments the `counter` field of the source document by the value of the `counter` param in the update operation. [The default scripting language is called Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/index.html), and the script can be as complex as needed. It is advisable to parameterize an inline script as above, to allow the compilation unit that results from compiling the script to be cached and reused by Elasticsearch.

With bulk updates, you need to know the ids of the documents that you wish to update, in order to form the bulk update operations.

#### 2. Update by query API

The [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) allows you to perform scripted updates on a set of documents that match a query.

The scripted update executes the same script against each matching document. A crucial difference then between update by query and bulk update when performing a scripted update, is that update by query cannot be parameterized with different argument values per document update; all updates perform the same scripted update.

An example of update by query

```
var updateByQueryResponse = client.UpdateByQuery<object>(b => b
    .Index("my_index")
    .Query(q => q
        .Ids(ids => ids
            .Values(1,2,3,4)
        )
    )
    .Script(s => s
        .Source("ctx._source.counter += params.counter")
        .Params(p => p
            .Add("counter", 1)
        )
    )
);
```

which sends the following request

```
POST http://localhost:9200/my_index/_update_by_query?pretty=true 
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.counter += params.counter",
    "params": {
      "counter": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Similar to scripted bulk updates, you have access to the `_source` document within the script through `ctx._source`.

With update by query, you don't need to know the ids of documents you wish to update; documents to update will be targeted by matching the query provided which can be a `match_all` query to update all documents.

Comment: wow thank's for the detailed answer. At the end it's only possible via script then - allright.

Comment: .. just to be sure.. I assume changing Id during this operation is forbidden?

Comment: Hm after reindexing V6.x data in V7 and performing this update operation:   operation[0]: update returned 404 _index: datapoints-batches-0efec950-3e13-4971-be78-bff50a06f0b8 _type: _doc _id: e6cd17b0-a311-4133-80dc-8e84826cb392 _version: 0 error: Type: document_missing_exception Reason: "[_doc][e6cd17b0-a311-4133-80dc-8e84826cb392]: document missing" I thought mapping types have been removed?